# ACRA не показывает в logCat IDE логи пойманной ошибки

Tags: java, android, eclipse, logcat

**Дано:**

Приложение пользует либу ACRA для отправки отчётов об ошибках. Ошибки ловит, отправляет.

**Проблема:**

При выкидывании приложением ошибки в logCat IDE (Eclipse) отображается процесс отправки сообщения об ошибке, но не показываются строки с описанием ошибки. В итоге, словив исключение, инфу о нём можно только у себя на сервере посмотреть, что адЪски неудобно...

**Вопрос:**

Я что-то делаю не так (код инициализации ACRA ниже) или так и должно быть и активировать сию либу надо только в релизной версии?

```
/**
* here we initialize ACRA crah reporter
* 
* @see https://github.com/ACRA/acra
*/
@ReportsCrashes(
formKey = "", // This is required for backward compatibility but not used
formUri = "http://I_AM_SURE_MY_DOMAIN_YOU_DO_NOT_NEED/acra/report.php",
customReportContent = { ReportField.APP_VERSION_CODE,   ReportField.APP_VERSION_NAME, ReportField.ANDROID_VERSION, ReportField.PHONE_MODEL, ReportField.STACK_TRACE, ReportField.LOGCAT },
mode = ReportingInteractionMode.TOAST,
resToastText = R.string.crash_toast_text)
public class MyApplication extends Application
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {
        super.onCreate();
        // The following line triggers the initialization of ACRA
        ACRA.init(this);
    }
}
```

**P.S.** Доки почитал, гугл потеребил - не помогло.

**UPD_0:**

Вот [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13920503/runtime-exceptions-are-caught-with-acra-and-not-displayed-on-logcat) пишут про аналогичную проблему, решённую путём понижения уровня фильтрации logCat. Но он у меня и так на уровне "verbose" стоит...

**UPD_1:**

Как выяснилось, на эмуляторе (Genymotion, nexus 4, ver.4.4.4) работает нормально. Т.е. после отправки рапорта ACRA выводит в logCat под своим тегом stackTrace ошибки. А вот на реальном устройстве (LG g3s, ver.5.0.2) не всегда в logCat пишет о завершении операции отправки (при этом отправляет без сбоев) и перестаёт писать логи, не доходя, таким образом, до сообщения деталей пойманной ошибки. Неприятно, жить можно с этим, но... Может можно как поправить?

**UPD_2:**

Судя по всему дело тут в **5** андроиде. Протестировал на планшете с **ver.4.2.2** - работает как надо (как и на эмуляторе (**ver.4.4.4**), упомянутом выше. А на nexus 4 (**ver.5.1**) не пашет (в смысле - нет stackTrace в логах Eclipse) как и на вышеупомянутом девайсе с **ver.5.0.2**.

**UPD_3:**

Проверил в logCat чрез командную строку (adb logcat) - все логи на месте. Видать проблема в Eclipse.

Comment: попробуйте выставить пермишен на чтение логов: `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_LOGS" />`

Comment: @Barmaley, не помогло( В доках пишут что с JB оно уже и не нужно (https://github.com/ACRA/acra/wiki/AdvancedUsage#adding-logcat-eventlog-or-radiolog-extracts-to-reports). А вы пользуете сию либу и у вас в IDE в logCat показывается выхлоп от пойманной ошибки?

Comment: Обновил вопрос.

Comment: Я использую ACRA, но как то не замечал что логи не пишутся. Может не обращал внимания? К тому же у меня настроено так, что ACRA работает только на продакшне, в дебаге он у меня отключен.

Comment: @Barmaley, обновил вопрос. Судя по всему дело в 5 андроиде. Ткнув пальцем в небо предположу, что поток приложения после краха по ошибке и его поимки ACRA умирает полностью, не успев выдать в логи stackTrace ошибки. На девайсах/эмуляторах с OS<5 stackTrace в логах IDE присутствует.

Comment: Запилил issue на github (https://github.com/ACRA/acra/issues/257)

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что проблема, была, вроде, в устаревшой версии библиотеки. Засим неактуально и невоспроизводимо.